# How do you do a for loop/for each in EJS?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, express, partials

I know it has to go inside <% %>, but I'm not sure if it's very different from a typical forEach/for loop. The documentation on the EJS site is pretty limited, so I came here.

```
<% include ../../partials/header %>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>List of all quotes</h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <!-- for loop goes here, inside flounder -->
        <%
        all quote stuff goes here
        author
        content
        wrap it in a link to its quote page
      </li>
    </ul>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note the link embeddedjs.com is now a casino site. EJS's main webpage moved to here: https://ejs.co/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So here's the example on embeddedjs:

```
    <ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

And here's what I did:

```
<% include ../../partials/header %> <
<body>
  <main>
    <h1>List of all quotes</h1>
    <ul>
      <% for(var i = 0; i < author.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%= author[i] %></li>
      <% } %>

      <% for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%= content[i] %></li>
      <% } %>

    </ul>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 22):

Let say you have a student JSON object with details of student name, year and course then you can loop through with forEach as follows.

```
<ul>
 <% students.forEach(function(student) { %>
    <li> Name:<%= student.name %> Course:<%= student.course %></li>
 <% }); %> 
</ul>
```

The same can apply for your author and quote question above

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use a `forEach` array method and pass the index as a second parameter and did something like this:

```
<% orders.products.forEach((order,index) => {%>
            <tr>
              <td><%= index+1 %></td>
              <td><%= order.description %></td>
              <td><%= order.price %></td>
              <td><%=order.quantity %></td>
              <td><%=orders.amount %></td>
              <td><%=order.salesTax %></td>
              <td><%=order.tax %></td>
              <td><%=order.amount %></td>
            </tr>
            <% });%> <% }%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 <% users.forEach(function(user, i){ %>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"> <%= i+1 %> </th>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.gender %></td>
    <td><%= user.status %></td>
    
</tr>
```

<% }); %>

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul> 
   <% for (const key in students) { %>
     <% const student = students[key] %>
     <li> Name:<%= student.name %> Course:<%= student.course %></li>
   <% } %>
 </ul>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.